# How to implement map with pattern matching

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, pattern-matching, higher-order-functions, map-function

I wanted to write a pattern matching implementation of `map`, so I wrote this:

```
const map = (f, [x, ...xs]) => {
  return (!x && !xs) ? [] : [f(x), ...map(f, xs)];
}
```

However, the compiler complains about the `xs` parameter in the recursive call:

> Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[any,
>   ...any[]]'.   Property '0' is missing in type 'any[]'

I also tried `[f(x), ...map(f, [xs])]`, but this produces a stack overflow error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried spreading the xs in the internal map call? map(f, ...xs)?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have pattern matching. You're using destructuring assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think the issue was the comparison of the ...xs argument via &&, that caused the recursion to never end. You only really care about if the next array prop to handle is there, the rest will be caught by the next recursion.

The compiler error comes from there being no type definition for the argument array, and tsc deduces one from the source: but the type [any, ...any[]] is too narrow. Typing the array with :any[] clears the issue.

I hope this helps.

```ts
const map = (f, [x, ...rest]:any[]) => {
  return (!x) ? [] : [f(x), ...map(f, rest)];
}

console.log(map(x=>x+10, [1,2,3]))
```

Comment: This seems to be working. The compiler still complains about the `rest` parameter as in my first example though..

Comment: See [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20map%20%3D%20(f%2C%20%5Bx%2C%20...rest%5D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20(!x)%20%3F%20%5B%5D%20%3A%20%5Bf(x)%2C%20...map(f%2C%20rest)%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(map(x%3D%3Ex%2B10%2C%20%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D)))

Comment: Had to fire up a local tsc, the codepen one clearly is conffed to ignore inferred type errors or something like that :)